# Add custom comparatorClass class in Solr

Tags: sorting, solr, comparator

I am newbie in **Solr**. I want to **add** a **custom comparatorClass** in Solr. I also need to use **fields - term and count** in my custom class which I have defined in my **schema.xml**.

Structure of indexing document :

```
"docs": [
      {
        "count": 98,
        "term": "age",
      },
      {
        "count": 6,
        "term": "age assan",
      },
      {
        "count": 5,
        "term": "age but",
      },
      {
        "count": 10,
        "term": "age salman",
      }]
```

I have stored **ngrams** with **term and their count** but **solr** gives **frequency by own** that I **don't** need. I want my **count frequency** which I have defined for each term. And that term and count, I need to use and want to **sort** with frequency(**count**) and then **edit distance** which I need to implement by creating **own class** in **comparator class** or there is something else which helps me. Please share..

How can I do this.  Any help please.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to add a custom comparator? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: @MatsLindh: I want to use name own defined fields - `term and count`. `Term` contains a word - 'age' and `count` contains - 'frequency of the word'. I `don't` want to use `solr pre-defined freq` value. I have to use my own which matches my requirement. How to start to build own class `'comparatorClass'`.

Comment: @iNikkz can you clarify your question with some example? Better edit the question with more details.

Comment: @sidgate: I have updated my question. Please check and give your views and help to create class in solr. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this without implementing a custom similarity class. The first requirement is (from your description) a straight forward sort on the count value, while the latter can be implemented by sorting on the value from the [`strdist()`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#strdist) function. You can also multiply or weight these values against each other [in a single sort statement](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Sort_By_Function) by using several functions.

If you really, really need to build your own scorer (which I don't think you need to do from your description) - these are usually written to explore other ranking algorithms than tf/idf, bm25 etc. for larger corpuses, a search on Google gives you many resources with pre-made, easy to adopt solutions. I particularly want to point out "This is the Nuclear Option" in [Build Your Own Custom Lucene Query and Scorer](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2014/01/20/build-your-own-custom-lucene-query-and-scorer/):

> Unless you just want the educational experience, building a custom Lucene Query should be the “nuclear option” for search relevancy. It’s very fiddly and there are many ins-and-outs. If you’re actually considering this to solve a real problem, you’ve already gone down the following paths [...]

Comment: I want to add class into Solr.

Comment: Yes, we understood that from your question, but why?

Comment: working on spell correction. I am getting suggestions of misspell word, So, suggestions are coming like this **word + freq**.I have indexed ngrams(1 to 5) in my documents,where each document contains term(ngram) which may be 1 to 5 -grams and its frequency(count) which I have inserted as per my needs. I have completed my configuration of schema.xml and solrconfig.xml. Now, suggestions of any word gives its frequency on the basis of schema.xml configuration(ShingleFilterFactory). But I want to use my own defined frequency(count) not the frequency of suggestion. So, how Can I do this?